# Open Browser on Click of ServiceWorker Notification

Tags: firebase, google-chrome, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I want to open the browser when a user clicks on the notification.

I have a firebase Project with Angular and i have a service worker registered which gets the notification. What Option is to set to open the browser on notification click ?

This is what i have so far and it does not work. ( I have it from [here](https://notifications.spec.whatwg.org/#using-actions) )

```js
self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
  event.notification.close();
  clients.openWindow("/prices");
},false);
```

It does also not work with absolute URL.

Comment: @frank-van-puffelen any ideas on this? or any pointers on handling click in firebsae service worker.

Comment: Have you tried using the promise .THEN .ELSE functions to check output/errors?

Comment: do you mean , on notification click the application should open in the new browser tab

Comment: clients.openWindow("/prices").then().else(err => {})

Comment: @ravi yes, thats what i want

Comment: @McMurphy ill try that as soon as possible

Comment: @Joniras https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52225110/notificationclick-event-service-worker/52232540#52232540         could you please take a look at it what is does is ,it checks whether the application  is open, by using variable appUrl which is URL of the application, if the application is not open ,it will open the application in new browser tab ,and  if the application is already open in browser tab  it will just focus on it.

Comment: @ravi yes this was the solution !! also some of this actually: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50755931/firebase-set-background-message-handler